# How should I encode my inputs for a classifier model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

```
match_id| radiant_win| duration| avg_mmr | avg_rank_tier | radiant_team | dire_team

10029   6903867218  True    971     9789.0  81  59,128,137,22,41    126,32,15,9,70

1627    6975504311  False   3240    9380.0  81  89,107,37,96,34     9,65,70,32,43

19104   6827705700  False   2896    8920.0  81  78,123,54,126,31    137,98,93,9,13

28289   6749424718  False   1817    8729.0  81  62,41,87,43,129 128,105,100,48,106

8217    6919222005  True    2037    8581.0  81  21,93,62,65,14  39,68,19,33,10

... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...

29332   6744847007  False   3453    NaN     33  101,54,84,35,135    68,104,31,76,1

29341   6744846716  False   1879    NaN     25  90,44,129,60,101    42,11,23,119,100

29342   6744846919  True    2394    NaN     24  67,46,11,86,7   90,14,87,4,80

29351   6744846917  False   2805    NaN     22  101,8,14,44,9   51,67,4,35,57

29354   6744846918  False   1617    NaN     21  18,14,126,75,104    15,84,73,72,25

129104 rows × 7 columns
```

Above is the data we gathered. We have two teams with 5 heroes picked (think of the number as a serial number, it's merely based on the order a hero is released)

Now there are in total 123 heroes in Dota2 (the serial number has a jump, in total there are 123), and our classifier aims to classify the win-rate given 5 heroes. It will be trained with the 129k matches of data to find combinations of heroes that are more powerful and has high win-rate.

However, we came across this problem that we're not sure how to encode the heroes when it comes to input for the model.

Apparently, given that there is no ordinality in the heroes, the number is not a good idea. As for one-hot encoding, 123 heroes would result in a [123, ] shape array for one hero, and with 5 hero in total it can result in a very large array.

Any ideas on how I should encode the heroes as inputs?

Answer (score 0):

One hot encoding is perfectly fine in this scenario. You could always perform [Principal Component Analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) on your one hot encoded data to reduce the dimension as well (but I do not believe you need to do that, or that it will even help in your scenario). You should try out different approaches and see what works best based on your experiments.

Don't forget to make sure that you avoid feeding your model redundant data like the match id, which do not have any effect on the result.

Comment: Thank you so much!! In this case, should I be doing one-hot encoding for each hero by splitting up the radiant_team column (for example, hero 9 got encoded as [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ... 0, 0] or encode the entire combination (for example, [1, 2, 4, 5] to [1, 1, 0, 1, 1])?

Comment: @DominikLi You should be doing the latter. Do you plan to perform one-hot encoding on both radiant and dire teams?